# Ruby on Rails and Devise associating id from one table to a foreign_key id in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I have created a user model using devise. In the comment model I set the comment `belongs_to :user`. Within the user model, I then set the `has_many: comments` relationship.

comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :comments
end
```

Inside the comment controller, I have the following code.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save

    end
  end

......

end
```

In the view within the index page I have this code inside an erb basically to pull the name of the user

```
<td><%= comment.user.first_name if comment.user %></td>
```

but it's not displaying anything at all?

Basically I have tables in the database, the User table and Comment table. I would like to associate the id of the user from the User table with the `foreign_key`, `user_id` in the comment table.

For example, I have logged in as a user with user id = 1 and created a comment. When I queried the database to check the comment the user_id was nil

```
#<Comment id: 19, Ticker: "Hello", MyComment: "Test", created_at: "2014-06-07 20:07:44", updated_at: "2014-06-07 20:07:44", user_id: nil>
```

Comment: Try build through the user -- `@comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])`. But your existing code *should* work. Is `current_user` set? Add a validation on `Comment` -- `validates_presence_of :user`.

Comment: add full controller code.

Comment: @Damien I added this validates_presence_of :user, sorry not quite sure what it's supposed to do? reading this now http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have this;

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save

    end
  end

......

end
```

Then successfully call this;

```
<td><%= comment.user.first_name if comment.user %></td>
```

This is because @comment contain only the user reference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried this it didn't work.

Comment: @cloudviz, does the user_id exist now? what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I am trying to display the users' first name next to the comment, no errors whatsoever but because it isn't being associated to a comment, it's displaying blank first_names.

Comment: @cloudviz, share the user details from the database and details of the comment just to be sure all fields (user_id and first_name) exit. Because you created the first comment with user_id=nil and have to create another where the user_id gets stored

Comment: User details is id = 1, first_name = "Joe", last_name = "Blogs" from the User table. I added this in the comments controller def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:Ticker, :MyNote, :user_id)
    end. Now I'm getting the error undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass after removing the if comment.user in this erb <td><%= comment.user.first_name %></td

Comment: Got it fixed now, silly me I had a duplicate def create ... end down below the comments controller!, which was causing the issue.